# Styled ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-progressbar

my goal is to create such view:

[image]

To achieve that I've created progress drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="ring"
                    android:innerRadius="0dp"
                    android:thicknessRatio="2.2">
                    <solid android:color="@color/dark_mint"/>
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item>
                <shape
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.17"
                    android:thicknessRatio="27">
                    <solid android:color="@color/mint"/>
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item>
                <shape
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.34"
                    android:thicknessRatio="27">
                    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
            <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:fromDegrees="270"
                android:toDegrees="270">
                <shape
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.31"
                    android:thicknessRatio="40"
                    android:useLevel="true">

                    <solid android:color="@color/light_red"/>
                </shape>
            </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The view seems to render **fine** on **Android 5** however when executed on e.g. Nexus5 (Marshmallow **Android 6.0.1**) it doesn't show at all. It seems using rings with ratio innerRadius/thickness spoils the thing.

I managed to fix that using only **ovals** with **paddings** but it forces me to use absolute dimentions like **dp** and the progress bar size can change.

Do you have any ideas on implementation ?

Comment: Even I had a similar problem... I too am waiting for a solution.